# Function to swap values of x and y does not work

Tags: function

I'm a complete noob at coding.  I wrote this function to swap the values of x and y, but it's not working. logic seems very simple, so I don't understand what's wrong. Can you help?

```
function swap (x,y) {
   x = y;
   y = x;
   return [x, y];
}
console.log(swap(2,3));
```

I tried to swap the values of x and y using a function that i wrote.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Thank you so much! Stackoverflow community rocks! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your function is that your modifying the value of x so you lose it. Then when you assign it to y your actually assigning the value of y that was stored in x.
You need another variable:

```
function swap (x,y) {
   const previous_x = x;
   x = y;
   y = previous_x;
   return [x, y];
}
console.log(swap(2,3));
```

But as you're returning directly the value, you can simplify it a lot:

```
function swap(x, y) {
   return [y, x];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function swap (x,y) {
  let temp;
  temp = x;
  x = y;
  y = temp;
  return [x, y];
}

console.log(swap(1,2));
```